# Is it alright to have an anchor type=button?

Tags: html

I've tried the following:

```
<a href="#" class='aclass'>Fires an event</a> //pops back up to page, not nice
<a href="" class='aclass'>Fires an event</a> //refreshes the page, not nice

<a type="button" class='aclass'>Fires an event</a> //does nothing but the event, good!
```

Just wanted to know if it is semantically acceptable to add a type attribute with value button to anchor tag as I don't recall ever doing it but perchance it happened now and actually worked.

Comment: It's an invalid attribute for the anchor element. The `type=""` attribute is only applicable to input and buttons. If you want to prevent scrolling, simply prevent default using `event.preventDefault()` when a click event is triggered on the `<a>` element.

Comment: Yeah I saw, awkward why it behaves with the same properties as an element with `type="button"` then?

Comment: Sometimes the browser will attempt to fix invalid HTML, but that is up to the browser to decide what it should be. The thing is that this kind of "intelligent fixing" behavior is not consistent throughout browsers and more importantly **semantically invalid**.

Comment: You can always validate your HTML at http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: @Terry the `type` attribute [is most certainly valid on `a` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-type). The value `button` is not though.

Comment: the semantic of the web is pretty simple and as it is simple, people tend to do what the **** they want with it, anchors are born to point to outside of the current context resources, buttons have no href, they are not there to mean anything, if they are context-free like outside of a form they are just stuff like a rectangle with text in it, if they are inside a form they will fire the "action" with the "method" and other fancy stuff of the form
so there's no semantic involved in anchors mimic buttons

p.s. and there is no need of RFCs to state that

Comment: @ROLO semantically there's a lot of difference. Buttons are intended to introduce dynamic behaviours, and as such follow the 'duck' rule: if it looks like a button, walks like a button and quacks like a button, use a button. An anchor on the other hand is meant to introduce connections across different hypertext pages. If it surfs, it should be an anchor - perhaps styled as a button. If it causes runtime in-page behaviour, it should be a button - perhaps styled as an anchor.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes that's what i was trying to say more or less, the point about buttons semantic is that they are context driven, i've used the form example to emphasize that buttons are more flexible than anchors, a button doesn't say anything to what will happen to a resource or a page in a form, if i push a button with a label like "Send" or "Save" that doesn't mean it has a semantic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is not a link but a button. So you should be using

```
<button type="button" class="aclass">Fires an event</button>
```

Styling it is just a matter of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `type` attribute of an anchor [must be the MIME-type of the target](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/a.html#a.attrs.type):

> The MIME type of the destination of the hyperlink.
>
> A string that
>   identifies a valid MIME media type as defined in [RFC 2046].

As `button` is not a valid MIME-type, your markup is specifically invalid.

If you want an anchor to look like a button, try `<a class="button aclass">`, and style it properly (yes you can use multiple space-separated classes on an element). If you want an actual button, just use `<button>`.